# How to add Virtual host IP and Domain in PHP Curl?

Tags: php, localhost, php-curl

Hi There I have added a virtual host in my windows Host file like this.

```
192.192.192.192       www.domain.com
```

I made some php curl request and it is working fine on my local but when I try on my live domain. There I don't understand where to add Virtual host. It is Windows Server. I know there is something in PHP curl. Anyone help how to send host IP and domain in PHP curl. Here is my working code on local machine.

```
$crul = curl_init();
curl_setopt($crul, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($crul, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($crul, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($crul, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.domain.com'); // where ruquest send
curl_setopt($crul, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($crul, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($crul, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($crul);
```